# Difference in grammar parsed by JavaCC and ANTLR

Tags: antlr, grammar, antlr4, javacc

JavaCC and Antlr wikipedia page says that both the parser generator works for grammar written in EBNF format. Does it mean that any grammar that can be parsed by JavaCC can also be parsed by ANTLR without modifying the grammar structure? If yes, why do we have a grammar repository for ANTLR (https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4) ? My current understanding is that some differences do exist between the grammars parsed by JavaCC and ANTLR. Can someone please point out the differences.

Comment: Don't be lazy. You can carry out experiments to know. As the two have so many unique features in each other, I don't believe "without modifying" is possible.

Comment: Read the documentation for the two tools.  A simplified explanation is that JavaCC essentially accepts any LL(k) grammar (with k defaulting to 1) and allows various kinds of lookahead specifications for cases where that doesn't work.  ANTLR 4 uses ALL(*), which you can read about in this paper http://www.antlr.org/papers/allstar-techreport.pdf .